# TraMineR subseqelist export to data frame

Tags: r, traminer

I'm fairly new to both R and TraMineR and am looking for some help. Right now I have a result set via the class "subseqelist." I need to get that result set into a data frame for further operations in R. However, when I try to use the `as.data.frame()` function it throws the error "cannot coerce class 'subseqelist' to a data.frame."

Can anyone help shed some light on what's going on? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

A `subseqelist` object is returned by the `seqefsub` function and contains several elements.
The list of the subsequences is in the `subseq` component (a list) and the supports and counts in the `data` component (a data frame).

Here is an example of how you can collect all that in a data.frame:

```
library(TraMineR)
data(actcal.tse)
## creating the event sequence object
actcal.seqe <- seqecreate(data=actcal.tse)
## extracting frequent subsequences
(actcal.fsubseq <- seqefsub(actcal.seqe, pMinSupport=.1))

## retrieving the data.frame with supports and counts
df <- actcal.fsubseq$data
## adding a column with the subsequence description as character strings.
df$subseq <- as.character(actcal.fsubseq$subseq)
df
```

Comment: @uspowpow Did you see the answer? Please indicate whether it was useful, and if not specify more precisely what you expected.

Comment: That was very helpful thank you! I essentially used your answer and came up with the following. I essentially just cast my TraMineR output as an array, so that you can index each catgory. Once you've extracted each column individually, then I just used cbind() to get them together and into a data frame. See below. Thanks again. 

temp.array <- as(object = fsubseq, Class = "array")
fsubseq_path <- as(object = temp.array[3]$subseq, Class = "character")
fsubseq_support<- temp.array[4]$data$Support
fsubseq_count<- temp.array[4]$data$Count